# Custom drag shadow with text

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am trying to create a custom drag shadow with text inside a small colored rectangle. Any help will be highly appreciated. Tried this in 2 ways:

a. Created a custom layout with a TextView and inflated it like this:

```
 public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drag_shadow, null);
    TextView textCount = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.textCount);
    textCount .setText("" + count);
    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new MyDragShadowBuilder(view1); // Tried with both view1 and textCount
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view1, 0);
}
```

Problem with this approach is since view1 is not added to view hierarchy, inside MyDragShadowBuilder, getView().getWidth() returns 0 and hence, nothing is drawn

b. Tried creating a custom TextDrawable class which extends Drawable. This showed the text but its very small though the font size i gave is 20sp.

TextDrawable class:

```
public class TextDrawable extends Drawable {

private final String text;
private final Paint paint;

public TextDrawable(Context context,String text) {

    this.text = text;
    int size = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.drag_shadow_font); //20sp
     Logger.log("TAG","Size="+size);  //60
    this.paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setTextSize(size);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
 //        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
//        paint.setShadowLayer(6f, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
//        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
//        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, 0, paint);
}

@Override
public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    paint.setAlpha(alpha);
}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    paint.setColorFilter(cf);
}

@Override
public int getOpacity() {
    return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
}
```

}

MyDragShadowBuilder:

```
private  class MyDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {

    // The drag shadow image, defined as a drawable thing
    private  Drawable shadow;
    private Point mScaleFactor;

    // Defines the constructor for myDragShadowBuilder
    public MyDragShadowBuilder(View v, int count) {

        // Stores the View parameter passed to myDragShadowBuilder.
        super(v);

        // Creates a draggable image that will fill the Canvas provided by the system.
       //            shadow = v
        shadow = new TextDrawable(getActivity(),"5000");

      //            shadow = new ColorDrawable(Color.LTGRAY);
        //ColorDrawable(Color.RED);

    }

    // Defines a callback that sends the drag shadow dimensions and touch point back to the
    // system.
    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point size, Point touch) {
        // Defines local variables
        int width, height;

        // Sets the width of the shadow to half the width of the original View
        width = getView().getWidth() / 2;
        Log.d("TAG", "width=" + width);

        // Sets the height of the shadow to half the height of the original View
        height = getView().getHeight() / 2;

        Log.d("TAG", "height=" + height);


        // The drag shadow is a ColorDrawable. This sets its dimensions to be the same as the
        // Canvas that the system will provide. As a result, the drag shadow will fill the
        // Canvas.
        shadow.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);

        // Sets the size parameter's width and height values. These get back to the system
        // through the size parameter.
        size.set(width, height);
        // Sets size parameter to member that will be used for scaling shadow image.
        mScaleFactor = size;

        // Sets the touch point's position to be in the middle of the drag shadow
        touch.set(width / 2, height / 2);
    }

    // Defines a callback that draws the drag shadow in a Canvas that the system constructs
    // from the dimensions passed in onProvideShadowMetrics().
    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {

        // Draws the ColorDrawable in the Canvas passed in from the system.
        shadow.draw(canvas);
       // canvas.scale(mScaleFactor.x/(float)getView().getWidth(), mScaleFactor.y/(float)getView().getHeight());
      //  getView().draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I am little late but it might be helpful for others, your 1st approach is correct but before **new MyDragShadowBuilder(view1)** you need to call -

**view1.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
view1.layout(0, 0,view1.getMeasuredWidth(),view1.getMeasuredHeight())**

This will give a proper dimension to your custom view